# How to get the data from ajax - JS & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the response from the ajax request below. when i remove `.sucess{}`, the data table is filtered with the response correctly. But i want to get the data(response) and pass it to variable `results`.

How do i get this done please?

```js
$('#statusFilter').on('change', function () {
    var results = false;
    var filter_value = $(this).val();
    dtListUsers.ajax.
        url('/user/json/' + filter_value)
        .load()
        .sucess: function(data) {
        results = data;
    }
    ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dtListUsers" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Even though this appears to be a duplicate, it's usually a good idea to make sure your snippet runs.

Comment: You can call onother function in success. Then you can assign value in tha new function.